# Error from a sub when calling .performclick() but works when you manually click?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, listview, recordset

I have a toolstrip menu button called Refresh.  The button calls the sub `LoadListview()`.  What this does, using a SQL Query and recordset to populate my listview with the oracle table contents.  Works just fine.

However recently I've been asked to just update the listview automaticly after a change has occurred.  So one of the columns is quantity and if someone edits the quantity from 10 to 9 rather than clicking refresh which query's the table again calling `LoadListView()` I just called `LoadListView()` in the code after making a change.

This is where it gets weird.  When you click refresh calling `LoadListView()` it works fine. 
When you call `LoadListView()` or even call the click for the refresh button in code `ToolStripButtonRefresh.PerformClick()` it errors on the below line with the following error:

`The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e0c in the message file for OraOLEDB`

```
Public Sub LoadListview()

rsMPCS_Con.Open(UCase(SQLQuery), conMPCS2, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)

.........
End Sub
```

So click refresh button which calls `LoadListView()` Fine.   Call `ToolStripButtonRefresh.PerformClick()` which calls `LoadListView()` then the error.   Can't figure it out.

```
Public Sub LoadListview()
    Dim IT As Integer
    Dim currentSize As Integer
    Dim arrValues(10) As String

    ConnectionCheck()

    Try
        iPageSize = cboPerPage.Text
        Try
            rsMPCS_Con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Try
            conMPCS2.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        If conMPCS2.State = 0 Then
            conMPCS2.Open(ConnectionStringToORACLE)
        End If
        rsMPCS_Con.PageSize = iPageSize
        rsMPCS_Con.CacheSize = iPageSize
        rsMPCS_Con.Open(UCase(LastSavedSTSQL), conMPCS2, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)

        If Not rsMPCS_Con.EOF Then
            iPageCount = rsMPCS_Con.PageCount

            If iPageCurrent > iPageCount Then iPageCurrent = iPageCount
            If iPageCurrent < 1 Then iPageCurrent = 1

            rsMPCS_Con.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent
            lblpageofpage.Text = "Page: " & iPageCurrent & " of " & iPageCount
            With ListView1
                .Clear()
                .View = View.Details
                .FullRowSelect = True
                .GridLines = True
                .CheckBoxes = False
                currentSize = 10
                .Font = New Font(.Font.Name, currentSize, .Font.Style, .Font.Unit)
                .Columns.Add("Description", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                .Columns.Add("Quan.", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Min. Qty", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Build No.", 65, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Rev.", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Weight/UOM", 110, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Home Location", 110, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Sub Location", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("SI_KEY", 0, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Email Alerts", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
            End With

            iRecordsShown = 0

            Do While iRecordsShown < iPageSize And Not rsMPCS_Con.EOF
                iRecordsShown = iRecordsShown + 1
                arrValues(0) = rsMPCS_Con("description").Value
                arrValues(1) = rsMPCS_Con("StockQuan").Value
                arrValues(2) = rsMPCS_Con("StockMin").Value
                'fixtures
                If rsMPCS_Con("BUILD_NO").Value = 0 Then
                    arrValues(3) = ""
                Else
                    arrValues(3) = rsMPCS_Con("BUILD_NO").Value.ToString
                End If
                If rsMPCS_Con("BUILD_NO").Value = 0 Then
                    arrValues(4) = ""
                Else
                    arrValues(4) = rsMPCS_Con("REVISION").Value.ToString
                End If
                '--------
                arrValues(5) = rsMPCS_Con("Weight").Value & " " & rsMPCS_Con("STOCK_UOM").Value
                arrValues(6) = rsMPCS_Con("LOCATION").Value
                arrValues(7) = rsMPCS_Con("SUB_LOCATION").Value
                arrValues(8) = rsMPCS_Con("SI_KEY").Value
                If rsMPCS_Con("Email").Value.ToString IsNot "" And rsMPCS_Con("StockMin").Value > 0 Then
                    arrValues(9) = "Enabled"
                Else
                    arrValues(9) = ""
                End If

                IT += 1
                Dim lsvi As New ListViewItem(arrValues)
                For Each row In lsvi.SubItems
                    If IT / 2 <> Int(IT / 2) Then
                        row.BackColor = Color.Ivory
                    Else
                        row.BackColor = Color.White
                    End If
                Next
                ListView1.Items.Add(lsvi)
                rsMPCS_Con.MoveNext()
            Loop

            For i As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                ListView1.Items(i).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                Dim rowreadconsume As OleDbDataReader
                query = "REDACTED"
                Using Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE)
                    Using CMD As New OleDbCommand()
                        With CMD
                            .Connection = Conn
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = query
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("SI_KEY", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(8).Text)
                        End With
                        Conn.Open()
                        rowreadconsume = CMD.ExecuteReader()
                        rowreadconsume.Read()
                        If rowreadconsume("CONSUMABLE") = 1 Then

                            Dim rowreadquan As OleDbDataReader
                            query = "REDACTED"
                            Using Conn2 As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE)
                                Using CMD2 As New OleDbCommand()
                                    With CMD2
                                        .Connection = Conn2
                                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                        .CommandText = query
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("SI_KEY", ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(8).Text)
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("LOCATION", Stockkey)
                                    End With
                                    Conn2.Open()
                                    rowreadquan = CMD2.ExecuteReader()
                                    rowreadquan.Read()
                                    If rowreadquan("QUANTITY_IN_STOCK") <= rowreadquan("LOW_STOCK_QTY") Then
                                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.Red
                                    Else
                                        ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.Black
                                    End If
                                End Using
                            End Using
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            Next               

            rsMPCS_Con.Close()
            'ListView1.Sort()
            'ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending
            With ListView2
                .Clear()
                .View = View.Details
                .FullRowSelect = True
                .GridLines = True
                .CheckBoxes = False
                currentSize = 8
                .Font = New Font(.Font.Name, currentSize, .Font.Style, .Font.Unit)
                .Columns.Add("Date/Time", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                .Columns.Add("Employee", 75, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                .Columns.Add("Transaction Amount", 125, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Job Number", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Machine No.", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Department No.", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                .Columns.Add("Comments", 400, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            End With
            PanelLoading.Visible = False
            ListView1.Select()
        Else
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            ListView2.Items.Clear()
        End If
        If rsMPCS_Con.State = 1 Then rsMPCS_Con.Close()
        If conMPCS2.State = 1 Then conMPCS2.Close()
        cmdNextPage.Enabled = True
        cmdNextPageEnd.Enabled = True
        cmdPrevPage.Enabled = True
        cmdPrevPageEnd.Enabled = True
        If iPageCurrent = iPageCount Then
            cmdNextPage.Enabled = False
            cmdNextPageEnd.Enabled = False
        End If
        If iPageCurrent = 1 Then
            cmdPrevPage.Enabled = False
            cmdPrevPageEnd.Enabled = False
        End If
        CLOSECONNECTION()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        If rsMPCS_Con.State = 1 Then rsMPCS_Con.Close()
        If conMPCS2.State = 1 Then conMPCS2.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to show us more code.  Are you closing that connection?

Comment: It gets opened and closed.  I have to watch what I show as a result of what I'm working on and where I'm working on it at.  But like I said if I click `Refresh` All that button does is call `LoadListview()`  So I don't understand how doing a `.PerformClick()` on the refresh button would produce the error I gave. There isn't much data on Google for this specific error.  Hoping someone's seen it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are still using ADODB for this?  Without more code, no one can help with this.

Comment: Ok I've added `LoadListview()` with just a cple sql query's redacted.  All that happens before this is a long query string is assigned to `LastSavedSTSQL` and then `LoadListview()` is called.  This portion of code was written years before me.  Not even sure how to convert it to something better.  But this works otherwise.

Comment: Empty Try-Catches is never a good sign.  Which line throws the error?

Comment: Yea I have time to clean things up, by no means will be I update what's in production yet.  The error occurs on the first line I had given earlier `rsMPCS_Con.Open(UCase(SQLQuery), conMPCS2, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)`  which works fine if I manually hit the refresh button which calls this sub.

Comment: I'll be leaving work in about 45 mins so if anyone assist or ask anything, I may not be back on till the morn.  LarsTech thanks for the assist so far.

Comment: any mouse events that performclick might not be hitting?

Comment: Remove the Try/Catch and debug it. Tell us the line that errors.

Comment: Your function is way too long. You should tear this apart into smaller tasks. That will be easier to maintain and easier to locate bugs.